# Filter row of table-1 on the basis of table-2 column value , no attachement between table-1 and table -2

Tags: mysql

I have 7 table like that

Clinic

```
  clinic_id     clinic_name    emailId              address
```

One to One mapping between clinic  and nurse table

Nurse

```
  nurse_id  nurse_name  nurse_emailid      clinic_id
```

Doctor

```
    doctor_id    doctor_name   doctor_email
```

Many to Many Mapping between the clinic and doctor

Doctor_clinic

```
    doctor_clinic_id  doctor_id   clinic_id
```

Patient

```
   pattient_id   patient_name     address
```

Many to Many Mapping between patinet and doctor_clinic

Doctor_clinic_patient

```
    patient_dotor_id   doctor_clinic_id  patient_id
```

One to Many Mapping between doctor_clinic_patient and doctor_patient_appointment

Doctor_patient_appointment

```
     appointment_id  appointment_time  appointment_status patient_doctor_id
```

appointment_status have three value- 'pending','cancelled','completed'

So, the senario is start from here

1. Select the clinic_id from the nurse_id (nurse table)
2. then on the basic of clinic_id , I want to select the doctor_clinic_id (doctor_clinic table)
3. then on the basis of doctor_clinic_id, I want to select the patient_id
4. then on the basic of patient_id,I want to select the patient details form    the patient table

the problem is that , I want to select only those patient from patient table which have a  appointment in appointment table of status 'pending'

I made the following query which work fine , get the patient row from db.But I want to filter this patient result on the basis of appointment status

**Query**

```
  Select * from patient where patient.patient_id in 

 (select doctor_patient.patient_id from doctor_patient where 

 doctor_patient.doctor_clinic_id in
 (select doctor_clinic.doctor_clinic_id from doctor_clinic where  

 doctor_clinic.clinic_id  in 
 (select nurse.clinic_id from nurse where nurse_id = 6) ))
```

Comment: This is a complex schema.  Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: yes, I made the query which find the patient details, but I don,t know how to filter on the basis of appointment_status

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen. I am posted the query. Please give any suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess a multiple JOIN will work here:

```
SELECT patients.* FROM patients JOIN (
  SELECT DISTINCT(p.patient_id) as pat_id FROM clinic c 
  JOIN doctor_clinic dc ON c.clinic_id = dc.clinic_id
  JOIN doctor_clinic_patient dcp ON dcp.doctor_clinic_id = dc.doctor_clinic_id
  JOIN patient p ON p.patient_id = dcp.patient_id
  JOIN doctor_patient_appointment dpa ON dcp.patient_doctor_id = dpa.patient_doctor_id
  WHERE dpa.status = 'pending'
) tmp ON tmp.pat_id = patients.patient_id
```

Comment: I am post the query in the question can you see that, please.Give  any suggestion if require

Comment: Have you tried my answer? It seems to suit your needs. BTW: I don't quite understand your query in question, since it filters out results by nurses, not by appointments (for which you asked)...

Comment: yes, you are right, but how can I apply that appointment filter my query. Thanks a lot for quick reply and give the solution of such complex thing.

Comment: One more thing, if I want to get the column from the  other table like some column from the appointment table and some column form the patient_doctor table , then what changes I have to made in your query.

Comment: Just remove the outer query and add appropriate fields to the `SELECT` statement in the inner query - i.e. replace `DISTINCT(p.patient_id) with doctor_patient_appointment.* for getting all appointments